# Axios cancel token cancelling request before even called

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, axios

So I am implementing axios call cancelation in the project. Right now looking at axios documentation it seems pretty straight forward https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation

So I did define variables on the top of my Vue component like

```
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
const source = CancelToken.source();
```

obviously on top of that is `import axios from 'axios';`

Then I have a method of fetching the API
On the top of the method I want to cancel out the request in case it is running so the last one cancels out if the user spams the filtering.

```
async fetchPartners(inputToClear) {
            source.cancel();
            ...

            try {
                const response = await axios.get(`../partners?limit=1000${this.createRequestString()}`, {
                    cancelToken: source.token
                });
                // Here you can see I did add the cancelToken to the request

                this.partners = response.data.data;
            } catch (error) {
                if (axios.isCancel(error)) {
                    console.log('Request canceled', error.message);
                }
                const fetchErrors = this.utilGlobalHandleErrorMessages(error);

                this.utilGlobalDisplayMessage(fetchErrors.message, { type: 'error' });

                return [];
            } finally {
                ...
            }
        },
```

So it is pretty straight forward, just took the code from axios documentation I gave you above, it should be working by logic. But what is actually happening, it doesn't even allow me to fetch the call, it is already cancelled out before I can call it. On console it shows me

```
Request canceled undefined
```

It just catches the error as if I am cancelling the call, but how can it be, because I am `source.cancel()` before the call.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: In your example, `source.cancel();` is invoked prior to your `try` block.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you should [throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#throttle) your requests instead of canceling the request.

Could you please try the following if throttle does not suit your requirement?

```
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
let source;

async fetchPartners(inputToClear) {
    if(source){
      source.cancel();
    }
    ...
    source = CancelToken.source();

    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`../partners?limit=1000${this.createRequestString()}`, {
       cancelToken: source.token
      });
      // Here you can see I did add the cancelToken to the request

      this.partners = response.data.data;
    } catch (error) {
      if (axios.isCancel(error)) {
        console.log('Request canceled', error.message);
      }
      const fetchErrors = this.utilGlobalHandleErrorMessages(error);

      this.utilGlobalDisplayMessage(fetchErrors.message, {
        type: 'error'
      });

      return [];
    } finally {
      ...
    }
  }
```